# Reload complete session if there are no modified buffers

Tags: session, vim

I have been using `mksession` to save my session files A,B,C in tabs.

```
:mksession! $HOME/mysession.vim
```

And I load the session using

```
" enables <leader>s to reinitialize session
nmap <leader>s :source $HOME/mysession.vim<CR>
```

But there are times when I just want to refresh to my three files A,B,C (may have been bouncing around looking at other files but in a saved state).  If I run the command twice, I basically get files A,B,C,A,B,C twice.  How can I modify the above session command to clear all unmodified buffer tabs and reload just the A,B,C files?

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the existing buffers via

```
:1,999bdelete
```

first.

Alternatively, have a look into plugins like [session.vim - Extended session management for Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3150); it seems to handle the reload of a session well.